# Google map v3 api not rendering correctly in bootstrap (no tab involved)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, rendering

I'm trying now for days to fix the problem that the google map is not rendered correctly on the website. [See Screenshot of correct and false rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBovN.png).

I hope you have a hint where the problem is coming from as I'm desperate by now. Worst case it's a nice collection of possible solutions for somebody else :)
The behavior I see is:

- List item Map partially loaded top left corner
- List item Double click on the unrendered area creates a second map beneath the first smaller map
- List item If page is reloaded multiple times quickly then about 10-30% of the times the map is displayed corrected

**Solutions tried but without success so far:**
 - resize the map `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')`

- Resize the map after receiving idle state 
  `google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');});`
- Resize the map and set center at the same time
- Manual trigger the resize event with a button
- Initialize the map after document ready 
  `$(document).ready(function() {initialize();});`
- Initialize the map after settimeout up to 10 seconds `setTimeout(initialize, 1000);`
- Detect parent div width & height and only initialize if big enough
- Assign parent div width & height to map-canvas
- Assign parent div width & height to .gm-style
- CSS: Assign width & height with px to canvas
- CSS: Assign width & height with 100% to canvas
- CSS: Assign width & height with combination of px & 100% to canvas
- CSS: Change max-width `#map-canvas img {max-width: none !important;}`
- CSS: Change max-width `#map-canvas img {max-width: none !important;}`

**Thoughts & Observations:**

Problem is sporadic which makes me believe it has to do with loading times
The canvas has immediately before initialization already the right dimensions and is fully visible (ie. no hidden tab etc.)
The additional buttons like Google logo, Report a mistake, contact etc are visible and at the right size. I believe this means that Google Map can't render on the full canvas for whatever reason for the map itself while it still detects the right dimensions

**Keywords used to find solutions:**
Google Map API v3 Problem, Google Map Rendering issue, Google Map top left corner, Google Map Bootsstrap problem

I have tried to simplify the html code as much as possible in case you want to take a look https://apptest.voiceoffriends.com/user.html

Thank you in advance for any hint or approach on how to fix the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  issue is this:

```
  function NoGeoLocationFound() {
                        clearTimeout(location_timeout);
                        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng();
                        map.setCenter(pos);

                    };
```

pos is  not  a    valid  `LatLng` (the  arguments are missing)

Comment: Thank you Dr. Molle! I wouldn't have thought about this being an issue as I couldn't see any error message trigger by Google Map on the console.

Comment: I remember the day when people could debug without the console... Alert is still a wonderful item.. Specially for mobile designs